# Multinomial logit with an rct

Tags: econometrics

If I'm running a randomized control trial, and the regression model I'm looking at is a multinomial logit, what would my specification be? I.e. what would the equation look like? Some dumbed-down detail would be appreciated. Also note, this is for a research proposal so this is like God running an experiment. No constraints of practicality apply

Comment: Have you done any attempt to answer this question by yourself? http://bfy.tw/BhZ5

Comment: I can google this stuff? Omg really? I had no idea. Did it occur to you I might have come here after having no luck with my own efforts? Or do you get off telling random people on the internet to do their own work? Without even knowing anything?

Comment: You would be amazed how many question in this site coming from new users are like "hey, can you do this for me?" (which are off-topic). Your question presented no evidence of effort, and as such, seems off-topic too. Hence my comment. At first it simply looks like "hey, give me the regression I need in a way a non-expert would understand it". Please show some evidence that is not really your case.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is not to submit a research proposal that contains methodologies you do not understand. Even if someone gave you the "dumbed-down detail", the devil is in the small details. There is risk you may misinterpret the results or accidentally engage in p-hacking, both of which would be harmful.

Comment: Appreciate the concern but this is for a course. I don't have to look at it again after a couple of days. The objective behind it is to see how well we understand experiment design and household models. My own training in econometrics is limited to ols and lpm so I'm considerably out of depth over here. And since I've already had my idea approved by the professor, I'm stuck. So a quick explanation about how to incorporate an RCT with a multinomial logit would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Bok There seems to be more information here you could add to the question, so it looks less like my other comments says. We appreciate good questions here.

Comment: @luchonacho Sorry if my question was vague, but i truly am at my wits end. This is the first time I'm looking at multinomial logit, and while I did spend the better part of yesterday understanding it, I'm still at a loss as to how I can incorporate my proposed rct with this. The idea is to essentially establish causation. I know there's trouble with this, but this is the final stretch of the semester and I just want to get done. Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Bok That is absolutely fine. There is no requirement of previous knowledge to be able to ask questions. Yet, you still need to state in the question that you did some effort. So my recommendation is that you edit your question, and add the information that you have given in your comments. That would suffice, imo.

Comment: Soo what you're saying is that you can't help me?

Comment: I am 100% sure that you are not stuck. You can go to the professor and tell her you feel out of your depth with the methodology and would like to submit another proposal.